# ¿Cómo realizar una operación aritmética sobre un dataframe?

Tags: r

Estoy importando un `dataframe` y quiero dividir los valores de sus filas en 10. Es decir, si una fila contiene el valor `120`, quiero `120/10=12`.

Por ejemplo:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(100, 120, 40, 200), b=c(300, 455, 67, 110))

    a   b
1 100 300
2 120 455
3  40  67
4 200 110
```

El resultado esperado

```
   a    b
1 10 30.0
2 12 45.5
3  4  6.7
4 20 11.0
```

Cómo lo hago?

Comment: edité tu pregunta por que tal como la tenías planteada puede que termine cerrada. Por favor revisa el ejemplo que agregué para ver si efectivamente es lo que buscas.

Comment: Perfecto Patricio. Muchas gracias. Intentaré poner ejemplos las próximas veces

Answer (score 0):

En **R** la operación de división `/` es vectorizada por lo que se puede aplicar directamente sobre el dataframe de la siguiente forma:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(100, 120, 40, 200), b=c(300, 455, 67, 110))
df/10

   a    b
1 10 30.0
2 12 45.5
3  4  6.7
4 20 11.0
```

¿Qué ocurre sin un `data.frame` contiene casos no divisibles? por ejemplo cadenas de texto:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(100, 120, 40, 200), 
                 b=c(300, 455, 67, 110), 
                 c=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
df/10

   a    b  c
1 10 30.0 NA
2 12 45.5 NA
3  4  6.7 NA
4 20 11.0 NA
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(left, right) : ‘/’ not meaningful for factors
```

Como verás las columnas `a` y `b` fueron correctamente divididas pero la `c` no, de hecho se emite un `warning` indicando justamente que la división no tiene sentido en este tipo de datos. En estos casos podrás aplicar la división a columnas en particular, por ejemplo:

```
df[,c(1,2)] <- df[,c(1,2)]/10
df
   a    b c
1 10 30.0 a
2 12 45.5 b
3  4  6.7 c
4 20 11.0 d
```

En este caso, con `df[,c(1,2)]` hacemos un recorte del `data.frame` para quedarnos con todas las filas pero solo las columnas 1 y 2 que son las numéricas y sobre estas aplicamos la división.

Comment: Me sale este error. Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator. He intentado hacerlo también sobre un archivo csv y txt y no me funciona

Comment: @Caro, lo que te dice el error es que estas haciendo `a / b` y  `a` o  `b` no son numéricos. No te puedo decir más por que desconozco tus datos, compartelos por ejemplo pegando la salida de este comando `dput(head(df))`. reemplaza `df` por el nombre de tu `dataframe`

Comment: structure(list(V1 = c("C001", "4", "8", "53", "56", "22"), V2 = c("C002", 
"12", "21", "2", "22", "32"), V3 = c("C003", "33", "33", "33", 
"33", "33"), V4 = c("C007", "19", "12", "21", "19", "12"), V5 = c("C00A", 
"19", "12", "21", "19", "12"), V6 = c("C017", "19", "12", "21", 
"19", "12").

Comment: @Caro, Te falta parte de la salida del `dput` pero lo primero que veo es que todos los valores son cadenas (están encerradas por comillas), no son numéricos, de ahí el error que te está dando. Tienes un problema previo, que es la importación de los datos, ¿puede ser que los códigos "C001", "C002", etc, sean nombres de columnas?

Comment: row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"). C001, C002 si son nombres de columnas, me he despistado al importar. Cuando pongo header=TRUE esto es lo que me aparece $ C001: int  4 8 53 56 22 32 22 19 12 21 ...
 $ C002: int  12 21 2 22 32 22 19 12 21 2 ...
 $ C003: int  33 33 33 33 33 33 19 12 21 2 ...
 $ C007: chr  "19" "12" "21" "19" ...
 $ C00A: chr  "19" "12" "21" "19" ...
 $ C017: chr  "19" "12" "21" "19" ... En todo caso entiendo que tengo que quitar las comillas, que no sé como hacerlo... y luego convertir los datos a numéricos con as.numeric, supongo.

Comment: Lo que te ocurre es que al importar seguramente no le estas diciendo que la primer fila corresponde a los nombres de las columnas, como son cadenas al entrar como datos hace que todo el dataframe sea del tipo cadena. Si estas usando `read.table` o similar para importar, debe haber algún parámetro tipo `header` que debes configurar en TRUE, revisa la ayuda. Si usas RStudio, hay una forma interactiva de importar muy buena, vas a `File->Import dataset`

Comment: La otra posibilidad es borrar la primer fila y convertir el `data.frame` a valores numéricos haciendo esto: `colnames(df) <- df[1,];df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df[-1,], as.numeric))`,  pero te recomiendo que resuelvas el problema en la importación.

Comment: Problema resuelto! Muchas gracias Patricio!